# can not import .sql file in mysql exported from sql server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have tried to import file with mysql command line

As Code,

```
mysqlimport test "D:\[dir...]\MAIN1.SQL"
```

but it does not works. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it gives error as, ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
import test

Comment: SQL Server uses a (completely) different syntax than MySQL. You can't just run a SQL script that is designed for SQL Server in MySQL (or any other DBMS that is). You **will** have to edit the script and adjust the syntax to MySQL.

Comment: I would be surprised if the generated SQL would be compatible to mysql

Comment: then @a_horse_with_no_name how can i resolve this?

Comment: As I said: you need to edit the file and fix the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**while executing this command the correct syntax is**

```
mysql --user='' --password='' databasename < your .sql file path" ;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test
< d:' at line 1

Comment: mysql --user='root' --password='' test < d:\[dir...]\MAIN1.SQL;

Comment: try to use like this and tell me what happens mysql --user='root' --password='' test < \d:[dir...]\MAIN1.SQL;

Comment: mysql -uroot -p test< /d:/.sql

Comment: this will help you surely .